# Make a ListView item glow from code

Tags: android, listview, glow

Here's my problem : I have an `Activity` that includes a `ListView` with different locations listed, and a `MapView` with markers to these locations.

What I want right now is, when one of the `MapView` markers is clicked, to have the respective `ListView` item to be selected and to glow (as if it was clicked).

I found the methods `ListView.setSelection(int)` and `ListView.requestChildFocus(View, View)`. The first one does almost what I want (if I have a long list, it goes through it until the item is visible) but it lacks a glow effect to explicitly show the item. About the second, I'm not sure what the second parameter is for (it's the previously focused view in the activity ?).

So, is there a way to have the item glow ? Like when you select it using a physical keyboard.

Thanks.

EDIT : subsidiary question, is it possible to get the standard drawable used as background when a ListView item is clicked ? Can it be found in R.attr like `listPreferredItemHeight` or something ?

Comment: The glow effect doesn't work in touch mode, so you have to somehow request that Android leave touch mode and call setSelection.  Don't know how off top of my head.  Maybe make the listview items focusable in touch mode?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I will take a look at this touch mode thing.
I added a subsidiary question, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of making the items selected, you want to make them checked. This allows you to use a `StateListDrawable` to change the appearance of the item, since items don't stay selected when they are in touch mode.  You have to put your `ListView` into single choice mode, make your listview item checkable, and use the `StateListDrawable` to change the appearance for checked items.

To put your ListView in single choice mode:

```
getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
```

Then when you want to highlight an item in your `ListView`, you do this:

```
getListView().setItemChecked(index, true);
```

I believe the root item of your row's layout must implement `Checkable`, you should be able to find example of `CheckableRelativeLayout` or `CheckableLinearLayout` online.

That makes your item "checked" but you still need to make it glow, so in your row's layout you must use a `StateListDrawable` to change its appearance when it is checked by adding this to the layout:

```
android:background="@color/list_view_item_selector"
```

and creating a `color\list_view_item_selector.xml` file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@color/selected_item" />
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

Comment: Alright, it works ! Thanks a lot, I could have spent days on that.

BTW didn't you mean "drawable\list_view_item_selector.xml" ?

Comment: I want to add that, in order to have the ListView scroll automatically, `setSelection()` has to be called (I don't know why) AFTER `setItemChecked()`.

Comment: Alright, last comment (o rly ?) :

I used a `CheckedTextView` in my case, I had no need to implement `Checkable` in a new class.

Comment: I'm trying to implement this myself, and all's good except it doesn't seem to accept my state_checked item in the state list drawable.  Do you set the background to be that of the listview, or that of the listviewitem?

Comment: @John: you set the background of the root element of the layout used for the list view item. The root element must be Checkable (like CheckedTextView or CheckableLinearLayout).